# It is impossible to map the nested List with Mapstruct - during the test it returns list = null

Tags: mapstruct

I'm still studying, so don't judge strictly)

Two questions: 1) An error in mapping - does not set the List object into mirror objects (in one direction the List is Null, in the other - out of bounds for length 0)
2) Optimization of mapping for hierarchy of objects

It turned out a lot of code in the inserts, but I still did not quite understand that it is not important to show the errors for analysis and showed everything as it is, just in case.
So there is an initial structure like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class BusinessEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    @Column(updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime modifiedOn;
    private LocalDateTime deletedOn;
    @NotNull
    private boolean SystemProtectedStatus = false;
    @NotNull
    private boolean SuspendedStatus = false;
    @NotNull
    private boolean blockedStatus = false;
    @NotNull
    private boolean deletedStatus = false;
    private LocalDateTime activeFrom;
    private LocalDateTime activeUntil;
}

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SystemRights extends BusinessEntity {

    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public SystemRights(@NotNull String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserRole extends BusinessEntity{

    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "rights_in_roles"
            , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "right_id")
            , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "role_id")
    )
    public List<SystemRights> systemRights;



    public UserRole(@NotNull String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public List<SystemRights> getSystemRights() {
        if (systemRights == null)
            systemRights = new ArrayList<>();
        return systemRights;
    }

    public void addSystemRights(SystemRights newSystemRights) {
        if (newSystemRights == null)
            return;
        if (this.systemRights == null)
            this.systemRights = new ArrayList<>();
        this.systemRights.add(newSystemRights);
    }

    public void removeSystemRights(SystemRights oldSystemRights) {
        if (oldSystemRights == null)
            return;
        if (this.systemRights != null)
            this.systemRights.remove(oldSystemRights);
    }

    public void removeAllSystemRights() {
        if (systemRights != null)
            systemRights.clear();
    }
}
```

I want to MapStruct it to a DTO like this: (one to one in fact)

```
@Data
public abstract class Dto {

    private String id;
    private String activeFrom;
    private String activeUntil;

    private boolean SystemProtectedStatus;
    private boolean SuspendedStatus;
    private boolean blockedStatus;
    private boolean deletedStatus;

    private String createdOn;
    //    private User createdBy;
    private String modifiedOn;
    //    private User modifiedBy;
    private String deletedOn;
//    private User deletedBy;
}

@Data
public class SystemRightsDto extends Dto{

    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;
}

@Data
public class UserRoleDto extends Dto {

    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    public List<SystemRightsDto> systemRightsDto;
}
```

To do this, I have piled these mappers below. - And here is the first question: - how in MapStruct to correctly inherit the mapping from the root entity BusinessEntity, which is the ancestor for all accounting objects in the system and not suffer from copy-paste to each child object, as I suffered here during training?

```
@Mapper
public interface UserRoleMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "id",
            expression = "java(getStringFromId(entity.getId()))")
    @Mapping(target = "activeFrom",
            expression = "java(getStringfromLDT(entity.getActiveFrom()))")
    @Mapping(target = "activeUntil",
            expression = "java(getStringfromLDT(entity.getActiveUntil()))")
    @Mapping(target = "createdOn",
            expression = "java(getStringfromLDT(entity.getCreatedOn()))")
    @Mapping(target = "modifiedOn",
            expression = "java(getStringfromLDT(entity.getModifiedOn()))")
    @Mapping(target = "deletedOn",
            expression = "java(getStringfromLDT(entity.getDeletedOn()))")
    UserRoleDto getDtoFromEntity(UserRole entity);



    @Mapping(target = "id",
            expression = "java(getIdFromString(dto.getId()))")
    @Mapping(target = "activeFrom",
            expression = "java(getLDTfromString(dto.getActiveFrom()))")
    @Mapping(target = "activeUntil",
            expression = "java(getLDTfromString(dto.getActiveUntil()))")
    @Mapping(target = "createdOn",
            expression = "java(getLDTfromString(dto.getCreatedOn()))")
    @Mapping(target = "modifiedOn",
            expression = "java(getLDTfromString(dto.getModifiedOn()))")
    @Mapping(target = "deletedOn",
            expression = "java(getLDTfromString(dto.getDeletedOn()))")

    UserRole getEntityFromDto(UserRoleDto dto);



    List<SystemRights> SystemRightsDtoToEnt (List<SystemRightsDto> dto);
    List<SystemRightsDto> SystemRightsEntToDto (List<SystemRights> entity);


    default LocalDateTime getLDTfromString(String string) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
        if (!isNull(string)) {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(string, formatter);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    default String getStringfromLDT(LocalDateTime ldt) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
        if (!isNull(ldt)) {
            return ldt.toString();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    default String getStringFromId(UUID id) {
        if (!isNull(id)) {
            return id.toString();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    default UUID getIdFromString(String id) {
        if (!isNull(id)) {
            return UUID.fromString(id);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}


@Mapper
public interface SystemRightsMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "id",
            expression = "java(getStringFromId(entity.getId()))")
    @Mapping(target = "activeFrom",
            expression = "java(getStringfromLDT(entity.getActiveFrom()))")
    @Mapping(target = "activeUntil",
            expression = "java(getStringfromLDT(entity.getActiveUntil()))")
    @Mapping(target = "createdOn",
            expression = "java(getStringfromLDT(entity.getCreatedOn()))")
    @Mapping(target = "modifiedOn",
            expression = "java(getStringfromLDT(entity.getModifiedOn()))")
    @Mapping(target = "deletedOn",
            expression = "java(getStringfromLDT(entity.getDeletedOn()))")
    SystemRightsDto getDtoFromEntity(SystemRights entity);


    @Mapping(target = "id",
            expression = "java(getIdFromString(dto.getId()))")
    @Mapping(target = "activeFrom",
            expression = "java(getLDTfromString(dto.getActiveFrom()))")
    @Mapping(target = "activeUntil",
            expression = "java(getLDTfromString(dto.getActiveUntil()))")
    @Mapping(target = "createdOn",
            expression = "java(getLDTfromString(dto.getCreatedOn()))")
    @Mapping(target = "modifiedOn",
            expression = "java(getLDTfromString(dto.getModifiedOn()))")
    @Mapping(target = "deletedOn",
            expression = "java(getLDTfromString(dto.getDeletedOn()))")
    SystemRights getEntityFromDto(SystemRightsDto dto);

    List<SystemRights> SystemRightsDtoToEnt (List<SystemRightsDto> dto);
    List<SystemRightsDto> SystemRightsEntToDto (List<SystemRights> entity);

    default LocalDateTime getLDTfromString(String string) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
        if (!isNull(string)) {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(string, formatter);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    default String getStringfromLDT(LocalDateTime ldt) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
        if (!isNull(ldt)) {
            return ldt.toString();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    default String getStringFromId(UUID id) {
        if (!isNull(id)) {
            return id.toString();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    default UUID getIdFromString(String id) {
        if (!isNull(id)) {
            return UUID.fromString(id);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The SystemRights transfer test works both ways, but the UserRole test fails. The test itself is like this:

```
public class UserRoleMapperTest {
    private UserRoleMapper userRoleMapper = Mappers.getMapper(UserRoleMapper.class);

    @Test
    public void testEntityToDto(){

        String  testDateStr = "2021-04-05T12:53:16.173706900";
        LocalDateTime testDateLDT = LocalDateTime.parse(testDateStr);
        UUID uuidTest = UUID.fromString("c095ad9f-37d4-479f-b88d-17df04f2437b");

        UserRole e = new UserRole();
        e.setName("Admin");
        e.setDescription("Super");
        e.setId(uuidTest);
        e.setActiveFrom(testDateLDT);
        e.setActiveUntil(testDateLDT);
        e.setSystemProtectedStatus(true);
        e.setBlockedStatus(false);
        e.setSuspendedStatus(true);
        e.setDeletedStatus(false);
        e.setCreatedOn(testDateLDT);
        e.setDeletedOn(testDateLDT);
        e.setModifiedOn(testDateLDT);

        List<SystemRights> eList = new ArrayList<>();
        e.setSystemRights(eList);

        SystemRights sr1= new SystemRights("Create");
        SystemRights sr2= new SystemRights("Read");
        SystemRights sr3= new SystemRights("Delete");
        eList.add(sr1);
        eList.add(sr2);
        eList.add(sr3);

        System.out.println("Testing testEntityToDto:  Entity have");
        System.out.println(e);

        UserRoleDto d = userRoleMapper.getDtoFromEntity(e);

        assertEquals(d.getName(),e.getName());
        assertEquals(d.getDescription(),e.getDescription());
        assertEquals(d.getId(),"c095ad9f-37d4-479f-b88d-17df04f2437b");
        assertEquals(d.getActiveFrom(),"2021-04-05T12:53:16.173706900");
        assertEquals(d.getActiveUntil(), "2021-04-05T12:53:16.173706900");
        assertEquals(d.isSystemProtectedStatus(),e.isSystemProtectedStatus());
        assertEquals(d.isDeletedStatus(),e.isDeletedStatus());
        assertEquals(d.isBlockedStatus(),e.isBlockedStatus());
        assertEquals(d.isSuspendedStatus(),e.isSuspendedStatus());
        assertEquals(d.getCreatedOn(),"2021-04-05T12:53:16.173706900");
        assertEquals(d.getModifiedOn(),"2021-04-05T12:53:16.173706900");
        assertEquals(d.getDeletedOn(),"2021-04-05T12:53:16.173706900");

        assertEquals(d.getSystemRightsDto().get(0).toString(),e.getSystemRights().get(0).toString());
        assertEquals(d.getSystemRightsDto().get(1).toString(),e.getSystemRights().get(1).toString());
        assertEquals(d.getSystemRightsDto().get(2).toString(),e.getSystemRights().get(2).toString());

        assertEquals(d.getSystemRightsDto().toString(),e.getSystemRights().toString());

        System.out.println("Testing testEntityToDto:  Dto have");
        System.out.println(d);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDtoToEntity(){

        String  testDateStr = "2021-04-05T12:53:16.173706900";
        LocalDateTime testDateLDT = LocalDateTime.parse(testDateStr);
        UUID uuidTest = UUID.fromString("c095ad9f-37d4-479f-b88d-17df04f2437b");

        UserRoleDto  d = new UserRoleDto();
        d.setName("Create");
        d.setDescription("Desc");
        d.setId("c095ad9f-37d4-479f-b88d-17df04f2437b");
        d.setActiveFrom("2021-04-05T12:53:16.173706900");
        d.setActiveUntil("2021-04-05T12:53:16.173706900");
        d.setSystemProtectedStatus(true);
        d.setBlockedStatus(false);
        d.setSuspendedStatus(true);
        d.setDeletedStatus(false);
        d.setCreatedOn("2021-04-05T12:53:16.173706900");
        d.setDeletedOn("2021-04-05T12:53:16.173706900");
        d.setModifiedOn("2021-04-05T12:53:16.173706900");

        List<SystemRightsDto> eListDto = new ArrayList<>();
        d.setSystemRightsDto(eListDto);

        SystemRightsDto sr1= new SystemRightsDto();
        sr1.setName("Create");
        SystemRightsDto sr2= new SystemRightsDto();
        sr2.setName("Read");
        SystemRightsDto sr3= new SystemRightsDto();
        sr3.setName("Delete");
        eListDto.add(sr1);
        eListDto.add(sr2);
        eListDto.add(sr3);

        System.out.println("Testing testDtoToEntity:  Dto have");
        System.out.println(d);

        UserRole e = userRoleMapper.getEntityFromDto(d);

        assertEquals(e.getName(),d.getName());
        assertEquals(e.getDescription(),d.getDescription());
        assertEquals(e.getId(),uuidTest);
        assertEquals(e.getActiveFrom(),testDateLDT);
        assertEquals(e.getActiveUntil(),testDateLDT);
        assertEquals(e.isSystemProtectedStatus(),d.isSystemProtectedStatus());
        assertEquals(e.isDeletedStatus(),d.isDeletedStatus());
        assertEquals(e.isBlockedStatus(),d.isBlockedStatus());
        assertEquals(e.isSuspendedStatus(),d.isSuspendedStatus());
        assertEquals(e.getCreatedOn(),testDateLDT);
        assertEquals(e.getModifiedOn(),testDateLDT);
        assertEquals(e.getDeletedOn(),testDateLDT);

        assertEquals(e.getSystemRights().get(0).toString(),d.getSystemRightsDto().get(0).toString());
        assertEquals(e.getSystemRights().get(1).toString(),d.getSystemRightsDto().get(1).toString());
        assertEquals(e.getSystemRights().get(2).toString(),d.getSystemRightsDto().get(2).toString());

        assertEquals(e.getSystemRights().toString(),d.getSystemRightsDto().toString());

        System.out.println("Testing testDtoToEntity:  Entity have");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

When I start "testEntityToDto" test i recieve:

Testing testEntityToDto:  Entity have
UserRole(name=Admin, description=Super, systemRights=[SystemRights(name=Create, description=null), SystemRights(name=Read, description=null), SystemRights(name=Delete, description=null)])

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.get(int)" because the return value of "com.example.cparty.dto.UserRoleDto.getSystemRightsDto()" is null

at com.example.cparty.UserRoleMapperTest.testEntityToDto(UserRoleMapperTest.java:77)

When I start "testDtoToEntity" test i recieve:

Testing testDtoToEntity:  Dto have
UserRoleDto(name=Create, description=Desc, systemRightsDto=[SystemRightsDto(name=Create, description=null), SystemRightsDto(name=Read, description=null), SystemRightsDto(name=Delete, description=null)])

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

```
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
at com.example.cparty.UserRoleMapperTest.testDtoToEntity(UserRoleMapperTest.java:149)
```

MapStrakt itself generated the following code: (in it I did not see how it sets the List for the target object)

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2021-04-06T11:03:58+0300",
    comments = "version: 1.4.2.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11.0.6 (JetBrains s.r.o)"
)
public class UserRoleMapperImpl implements UserRoleMapper {

    @Override
    public UserRoleDto getDtoFromEntity(UserRole entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        UserRoleDto userRoleDto = new UserRoleDto();

        userRoleDto.setSystemProtectedStatus( entity.isSystemProtectedStatus() );
        userRoleDto.setSuspendedStatus( entity.isSuspendedStatus() );
        userRoleDto.setBlockedStatus( entity.isBlockedStatus() );
        userRoleDto.setDeletedStatus( entity.isDeletedStatus() );
        userRoleDto.setName( entity.getName() );
        userRoleDto.setDescription( entity.getDescription() );

        userRoleDto.setId( getStringFromId(entity.getId()) );
        userRoleDto.setActiveFrom( getStringfromLDT(entity.getActiveFrom()) );
        userRoleDto.setActiveUntil( getStringfromLDT(entity.getActiveUntil()) );
        userRoleDto.setCreatedOn( getStringfromLDT(entity.getCreatedOn()) );
        userRoleDto.setModifiedOn( getStringfromLDT(entity.getModifiedOn()) );
        userRoleDto.setDeletedOn( getStringfromLDT(entity.getDeletedOn()) );

        return userRoleDto;
    }

    @Override
    public UserRole getEntityFromDto(UserRoleDto dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        UserRole userRole = new UserRole();

        userRole.setSystemProtectedStatus( dto.isSystemProtectedStatus() );
        userRole.setSuspendedStatus( dto.isSuspendedStatus() );
        userRole.setBlockedStatus( dto.isBlockedStatus() );
        userRole.setDeletedStatus( dto.isDeletedStatus() );
        userRole.setName( dto.getName() );
        userRole.setDescription( dto.getDescription() );

        userRole.setId( getIdFromString(dto.getId()) );
        userRole.setActiveFrom( getLDTfromString(dto.getActiveFrom()) );
        userRole.setActiveUntil( getLDTfromString(dto.getActiveUntil()) );
        userRole.setCreatedOn( getLDTfromString(dto.getCreatedOn()) );
        userRole.setModifiedOn( getLDTfromString(dto.getModifiedOn()) );
        userRole.setDeletedOn( getLDTfromString(dto.getDeletedOn()) );

        return userRole;
    }

    @Override
    public List<SystemRights> SystemRightsDtoToEnt(List<SystemRightsDto> dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<SystemRights> list = new ArrayList<SystemRights>( dto.size() );
        for ( SystemRightsDto systemRightsDto : dto ) {
            list.add( systemRightsDtoToSystemRights( systemRightsDto ) );
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public List<SystemRightsDto> SystemRightsEntToDto(List<SystemRights> entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<SystemRightsDto> list = new ArrayList<SystemRightsDto>( entity.size() );
        for ( SystemRights systemRights : entity ) {
            list.add( systemRightsToSystemRightsDto( systemRights ) );
        }

        return list;
    }

    protected SystemRights systemRightsDtoToSystemRights(SystemRightsDto systemRightsDto) {
        if ( systemRightsDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        SystemRights systemRights = new SystemRights();

        systemRights.setId( getIdFromString( systemRightsDto.getId() ) );
        systemRights.setCreatedOn( getLDTfromString( systemRightsDto.getCreatedOn() ) );
        systemRights.setModifiedOn( getLDTfromString( systemRightsDto.getModifiedOn() ) );
        systemRights.setDeletedOn( getLDTfromString( systemRightsDto.getDeletedOn() ) );
        systemRights.setSystemProtectedStatus( systemRightsDto.isSystemProtectedStatus() );
        systemRights.setSuspendedStatus( systemRightsDto.isSuspendedStatus() );
        systemRights.setBlockedStatus( systemRightsDto.isBlockedStatus() );
        systemRights.setDeletedStatus( systemRightsDto.isDeletedStatus() );
        systemRights.setActiveFrom( getLDTfromString( systemRightsDto.getActiveFrom() ) );
        systemRights.setActiveUntil( getLDTfromString( systemRightsDto.getActiveUntil() ) );
        systemRights.setName( systemRightsDto.getName() );
        systemRights.setDescription( systemRightsDto.getDescription() );

        return systemRights;
    }

    protected SystemRightsDto systemRightsToSystemRightsDto(SystemRights systemRights) {
        if ( systemRights == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        SystemRightsDto systemRightsDto = new SystemRightsDto();

        systemRightsDto.setId( getStringFromId( systemRights.getId() ) );
        systemRightsDto.setActiveFrom( getStringfromLDT( systemRights.getActiveFrom() ) );
        systemRightsDto.setActiveUntil( getStringfromLDT( systemRights.getActiveUntil() ) );
        systemRightsDto.setSystemProtectedStatus( systemRights.isSystemProtectedStatus() );
        systemRightsDto.setSuspendedStatus( systemRights.isSuspendedStatus() );
        systemRightsDto.setBlockedStatus( systemRights.isBlockedStatus() );
        systemRightsDto.setDeletedStatus( systemRights.isDeletedStatus() );
        systemRightsDto.setCreatedOn( getStringfromLDT( systemRights.getCreatedOn() ) );
        systemRightsDto.setModifiedOn( getStringfromLDT( systemRights.getModifiedOn() ) );
        systemRightsDto.setDeletedOn( getStringfromLDT( systemRights.getDeletedOn() ) );
        systemRightsDto.setName( systemRights.getName() );
        systemRightsDto.setDescription( systemRights.getDescription() );

        return systemRightsDto;
    }
}
```

Well, maybe the matter is in my environment (the whole pom.xml did not fit):

```
<org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
<artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>


                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `Mapping#expression` MapStruct will copy that as is without any checks.

There are way to many `expression`(s) in this question. I would suggest either doing the mapping by hand, or leave it up to MapStruct to do it.

You can actually remove all the `@Mapping` and everything should work correctly.